# Why do I get incorrect result using SUM()

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been trying to write a `SQL` query which sums columns. Here's the query:

```
SELECT `p`.`project_id`          AS `project_id`, 
       Sum(`r`.`expected_cost`)  AS `total_expected_cost`, 
       Sum(`r`.`expected_delay`) AS `total_expected_delay`, 
       Sum(`resp`.`cost`)        AS `project_total_mitigation_cost` 
FROM   ( ( ( `risks` `r` 
             JOIN `tasks` `t` 
               ON (( `t`.`task_id` = `r`.`task_id` )) ) 
           JOIN `projects` `p` 
             ON (( `t`.`project_id` = `p`.`project_id` )) ) 
         LEFT JOIN `responses` `resp` 
                ON (( `resp`.`risk_id` = `r`.`risk_id` )) ) 
GROUP  BY `p`.`project_id`
```

The result of the summation for the columns is way too high. `expected-cost, expected_delay, cost` can not be `NULL`.

Sample Data:

```
**************************
        projects
**************************
project_id    project_name
    1             alpha
    2             beta
    3             gamma
    4             delta
```

---

```
*******************************************************
                    tasks
*******************************************************
    task_id    project_id     name        
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
     5              1         mobile        
     45             1         keyboard           
     9              3         bottle          
     20             4         card
```

---

```
*********************************************************
                        risks
*********************************************************
    risk_id    task_id     expected_cost    expected_delay    
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
     1           5            1400.00        5.0
     2           45           300.00         4.0  
     3           9            10.00          10.0
     4           20           0.00           100.0
```

---

```
*******************************************************
                        responses
*******************************************************
    risk_id    response_id     cost        
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
     1         7              1500.00        
     2         9              900.00           
     3         13             80.00          
     4         2              1.00
```

---

```
*********************************************************************************************
                                 desired result of query
*********************************************************************************************
  project_id    total_expected_cost     total_expected_delay   project_total_mitigation_costs        
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
     1              1700.00                        9.0                     2400.00
     2              0.00                           0.0                     0.00
     3              10.00                          10.0                    80.00
     4              0.00                           100.0                   1.00
```

---

A little explanation to go with the sample data:

A project has tasks and tasks have risks and risks have responses. risks have expected costs and expected_delay. responses have costs.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is usually caused because the joins are along different dimensions, causing a cartesian product.  Without sample data or more information about the data layout, it is hard to say which join(s) are causing the problem.

Comment: Could you show the schema and some sample data for the tables?

Answer (score 1):

To debug this, change the select clause to count(*)

- Then run count on the first table
- Add each join one at a time
- If the  count increases more than expected, you'll know which JOIN is causing
  the problem.

Once you get the joins resolved and the count(*) is proper, put the regular select clause back in

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's causing your sums to return higher numbers but your parenthesis in your `from` clause might be off. It's best to remove them since they're not necessary.

Also, you should select from the `projects` table and 
left join the remaining tables because you want 1 row per project.

```
select p.project_id,
    sum(expected_cost) total_expected_cost,
    sum(expected_delay) total_expected_delay,
    sum(cost) project_total_mitigation_cost
from projects p
left join tasks t on t.project_id = p.project_id
left join responses r on r.project_id = p.project_id
group by p.project_id
```